# PHP GET problem - no form $_GET data is present

Tags: php, forms, get

I have a simple PHP form which displays inputs with values from a mysql DB and sends the form results to another page which updates a db table based on the `GET` results:

```
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "      <th>Project No</th>
    <th>Customer Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>";

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {     
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input value=" . $row['project_no'] . "></input></td>";
    echo "<td><input value='" . $row['cust_name'] . "'></input></td>";
    echo "<td><input value='" . $row['description'] . "'></input></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Update' />";
echo "</form>";
```

In `updateprojects.php` when I do:

```
echo $_GET['project_no'].$_GET['cust_name'].$_GET['description'];
```

I don't see any values. Why is this?

Comment: What does print_r($_REQUEST) brings up?

Comment: You may want to investigate using HEREDOCS (http://php.net/heredoc) instead of echoes like you are. They make life far easier since you don't have to escape quotes and whatnot.

Comment: Since you are creating form inputs whit a loop this(see my answer) should work for you, just grab an id of row/record from the database too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the input field you need to specify the parameter name with the "name" attribute.

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><input name=\"project_no\" value=" . $row['project_no'] . "></input></td>";
echo "<td><input name=\"cust_name\" value='" . $row['cust_name'] . "'></input></td>";
echo "<td><input name=\"description\" value='" . $row['description'] . "'></input></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: He is looping results. What if there is 2 or more rows there would be 2 or more fields with the same name. Check my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You are forgetting the input names:

```
<td><input name='project_no' value=" . $row['project_no'] . "></input></td>
```

If you don't do this php doesn't know what you mean by 'project_no'. Each input needs a name.

Answer (score 3):

It is because you do not assign names to the input tags:

```
echo "<td><input name=\"project_no\" value=\"" . $row['project_no'] . \"></input></td>
```

The above should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs have no `name` attribute

Comment: in this case div will not work properly, because you need an object form to send, and a div tag is property. Will not work, but if you really want to use div tag, then you will need to work with javascript (take a look at jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are creating form inputs with a loop this should work for you (you can't have 2 input fields with same name), just grab an id of row/record from the database too:

```
echo "<form method='get' action='updateprojects.php'>";
                echo "<table>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "      <th>Project No</th>
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>";

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                    {       
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo '<td><input value="' . $row['project_no'] .'" name="form['.$row['id'].']['project_no']"/></td>';
                        echo '<td><input value="' . $row['cust_name'] .'" name="form['.$row['id'].']['cust_name']"/></td>';
                        echo '<td><input value="' . $row['description'] .'" name="form['.$row['id'].']['description']"/></td>';
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                echo "</table>";
                echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />';
                echo "</form>";

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    foreach($_GET['form'] as $id=>$column){

        //update your database where id=$id. This is just testing
        echo 'Row '.$id .' =>'. $column['project_no'].'-'.$column['cust_name'].'-'.$column['description'];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `name=""` attribute to your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Something that has helped me in the past, is to use the Net tab in Firebug and enable the Persist option to see what the browser is actually sending back. In one case, the form had duplicate entries for some for fields, but the second entry wasn't sending the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Please inform the type of submit, or hidden text. And / or verify that you are returning data from sql query.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that you need to have a name="project_no" in you HTML input.